# Azure Cosmos DB connection issue using private links

Tags: java, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've created a private endpoint/link for the Cosmos DB. When I am trying to connect it the DB from an Java application as below code

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient("https://hostaddr.privatelink.documents.azure.com:443",
                "key...",
                new ConnectionPolicy(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);
//db operations /query using client object
```

It fails with below error

```
Failed to retrieve database account information. com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <hostaddr.privatelink.documents.azure.com>  > doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.documents.azure.com, *.sql.cosmosdb.azure.com, *.sql.cosmos.azure.com]
```

Just wondering if any configurations are required to connect over a private link.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints#current-limitations

Comment: I believe you may not touch the limitation of cosmos db private link. The connectionPolicy is Gateway as default. So how you execute your java application in the vm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Private Link works. Please refer to [Configure Azure Private Link for an Azure Cosmos account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints) for how to configure Private Link.

The endpoint for the Cosmos client is the same as it normally is. Looks like you're using our Core (SQL) API so this would be [your-account-name].documents.azure.com.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right- the end point URL remains same. It was rather DNS issue for me.